# How to handle my .htaccess in order to redirect correctly to two subfolders?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I placed my main Wordpress website (http://www.marcozanetti.it) in a subfolder of www called 'blog'.
I'd like, when the user goes to www.marcozanetti.it, to be redirected to http://www.marcozanetti.it/blog. This happens, and works.

This is the .htaccess file that allows me to do that:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Now I imported another Wordpress website, that I placed in a subfolder, called 'martiemarco'.

I noticed that if I go to http://www.marcozanetti.it/martiemarco I can see the home page, but if I click on a link like http://www.marcozanetti.it/martiemarco/la-lista-nozze/ I'm not getting the right page. I get a page with the same layout of http://www.marcozanetti.it/blog, saying the category or post does not exist.

I think this is due to the .htaccess rules but... how can I achieve the redirection from http://www.marcozanetti.it to http://www.marcozanetti.it/blog without breaking the references inside http://www.marcozanetti.it/martiemarco?

Thank you

Comment: Do you also have a `/martiemarco/.htaccess`?

Comment: Oh yes! And I didn't recall of that! -.-

It contains


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I tried but apparently it's not enough. Anyway Panama Jack answer below worked, so your fix was part of what I needed :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Place this in the .htaccess file in the root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then place this in the **.htaccess** file inside **martiemarco** directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /martiemarco/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /martiemarco/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```